# Symfony FormEvent. Entities passed to the choice field must be managed

Tags: symfony

I try to use EventListener but i have error:
Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?

ExampleType.php

```
$builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $data = $event->getData();

                $category = $data->getCategory();
                $tagi = null === $category ? array() : $category->getTags();

                $form->add('tags', 'entity', array(
                    'class'       => 'MyAppBundle:Tag',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'choices'     => $tagi,
                ));
            }
        );
```

//Category.php (entity)

```
/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}
```